# List files if there are too many of them

Tags: error, open

I often want to open files using the wildcards like

```
:e **/foo.bar
```

However every now and then I get an

```
E77: Too many file names
```

What I would like to have would be to add to that error message a list of the files found. That way, I can get the path to the one I want. I know that I can do something like

```
:arga **/foo.bar
:ls
```

But I would like to have it run automatically. For example populating the `quickfix` list, or something like that.

An idea would be to catch the `E77` and run some command to list them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Completion

Use `<tab>` to complete a filename. If you know there are going to be many candidates then you can use `<c-d>` to list out the candidates. May want to look into `'wildmenu'` & `'wildemode'` settings as well.

#### Argument List

You can use `:next` with your argument to populate the argument list.

```
:next **/foo
```

Now you can use `:next`/`:prev` to move along the argument list. Use `:args` to show the list.

#### Catching the error with `try`/`catch`

In order to catch `E77` you will need to create a custom command and then use `:try` & `:catch` blocks.

```
command! -complete=file -nargs=1 -bar EList call s:elist(<f-args>)
function! s:elist(path)
    try
        silent execute 'edit ' . a:path
    catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E77:/
        cexpr getcompletion(a:path, 'file')
        cwindow
    endtry
endfunction
```

Comment: I like the cexpr/cwindow; learned something new

Comment: Didn't know `cexpr` exists, +1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like `quickfix` in this case, i think `input` is better. I did both of them, choose the one you like.

```
function! s:edit(pattern)
  let files = glob(a:pattern, 0, 1)

  " do nothing if no file matches
  if empty(files) | return | endif

  " open single result
  if len(files) == 1
    exec 'e ' . files[0]
    return
  endif

  " otherwise warn and populate qflist
  " echohl WarningMsg
  " echo "too many files : \n\n" . join(files, "\n")
  " echohl None

  " call setqflist(map(files, '{"filename": v:val}'))
  " copen

  " otherwise let user select one
  let items = map(deepcopy(files), ' (v:key+1) . " : " . v:val ')
  let choice = input(
        \ "too many files : \n\n" . join(items, "\n") . "\n\nselect file : ")
  if empty(choice) || choice <= 0 || choice > len(files)
    return
  endif
  exec 'e ' . files[choice - 1]
endfunction

command! -nargs=+ -complete=file E call s:edit(<q-args>)
```

I don't use it. I prefer [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim).